# How to write maximum value of tree view in odoo?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I have one tree view have 3 columns . I wanted to get maximum of each column in function field ?

```
class feeder_data(osv.Model):
    _name = "feeder.data"
    _rec_name= "company_id1"
    _columns = {
        'company_id1': fields.many2one('res.company', 'Substation', required=True),
        'combine2':fields.one2many('data.value','combine','Details'),
        'max_mw': fields.function(_amount_line, string='Subtotal',type='integer'),
           }
class data_value(osv.Model):
    _name = "data.value"
    _rec_name = "mega_wat"
    _columns={
        'Hours':fields.integer('Hours'),
        'mega_wat':fields.integer('Mega Watts'),
        'combine':fields.many2one('feeder.data','details'),
    }
```

Here I do have tree view in `data.value`. In this class I have `mega_wat` field here I will enter values in `hourly_feeder` class i have one field as `max_wt` i wanted to have function field with max of `mega_wat` in it

Comment: Please elaborate your question

Answer (score 2):

First, create the max function in your model:

```
def _get_max_of_tree(self,cr,uid,ids,context=None):
    res={}
    for o in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context):
        res[o.id] = max(0.col1 , o.col2, o.col3)
    return res
```

then create a function field for it

```
_columns = { 
            ...
            'mymax' : fields.function(_get_max_of_tree, type='float'),
            ...
           }
```

EDIT: 
In you situation, it should be like this:

```
class feeder_data(osv.Model):
    _name = "feeder.data"
    _rec_name= "company_id1"

    def _amount_line(self,cr,uid,ids,context=None):
        res={}        
        for fd in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context):
            res[fd.id] = max([dv.mega_wat for dv in fd.combine2])
        return res

    _columns = {
        'company_id1': fields.many2one('res.company', 'Substation', required=True),
        'combine2':fields.one2many('data.value','combine','Details'),
        'max_mw': fields.function(_amount_line, string='Subtotal',type='integer'),
           }
```

Comment: pool.get is needed and what is that argument name in function please reply me

Comment: If you're referring to the same model then you don't need it. Those 2 args shouldn't be here so I took them out :)

Comment: same module but different class they are so

Comment: I did some mistake, res[o.id] should be res[fd.id].

Comment: Could you try printing fd.combine2 before the max calculation line?

Answer (score -1):

Use Built in Max function.

Help on built-in function max in module **builtin**:

```
max(...)
    max(iterable[, key=func]) -> value
    max(a, b, c, ...[, key=func]) -> value

    With a single iterable argument, return its largest item.
    With two or more arguments, return the largest argument.
```

Or you can define your own function.

```
def max_number(a, b, c):
    Max = a
    if b > Max:
        Max = b
    if c > Max:
        Max = c
    return Max
```

Your functional fields should be like this,

```
def _amount_line(self, cr, uid, ids, field_names, arg=None, context=None):
    res = {}
    for obj in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        max = 0
        for data in obj.combine2:
            if data.mega_wat > max:
                max = data.mega_wat

        res[obj.id] = max
    return res
```

Comment: bro i have edited my qun please help me how can i ge maximum of that column i.e 'mege_wat'

Comment: the approach of @P.InEstiCienT is what the use is  looking for

Comment: @Sharma: `"data.value"` doesn't contain that three columns, then from which I can find the max value ? did you have observe that model ? To find max value out of three columns there must be three columns present in that model.

Comment: @Sharma: `P.InEstiCienT` has apply the same logic what I have written over here in my answer.